# Long figure caption causing footnote to skip a number in RMarkdown file (PDF/Latex)

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, figure, footnotes

**Having a long figure caption in an Rmarkdown file is causing the footnote numbering to skip a number:**

---

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-02-27"
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

This is a sentence with a footnote \footnote{Footnote 1}.

```{r fig1, echo=FALSE, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE,out.width="50%", fig.cap="This is a long figure caption. This is a long figure caption. This is a long figure caption. This is a long figure caption. \\protect\\footnotemark"}

plot(mtcars$mpg)
```

\footnotetext{Footnote 2}

This is a sentence with a third footnote \footnote{Footnote 3}.
````

---

**This causes it to skip footnote 2:**

[image: Rmarkdown output displaying a skipped footnote number]

[image: Bottom of Rmarkdown file displaying a skipped footnote number]

**This does not happen with shorter figure captions. Is this a bug, or is there a way around this?**

Comment: I filed an issue with Rstudio/Rmarkdown (https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/2456) and it appears to be a known limitation with LaTeX, not an issue with Rmarkdown. There is currently no resolution.